# simple html dom display specific <tr></tr>

Tags: html, dom

How do I display only those that contain a.png?  It should display the entire `<tr></tr>` of those that contain a.png

```
<tr>
<td>57</td>   
<td><img src="z.png" width="40px" alt="z" title="z"></td>   
<td>Apples</td>     
<td>3341</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>44</td>   
<td><img src="a.png" width="40px" alt="a" title="a"></td>   
<td>Tree</td>     
<td>4341</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>57</td>   
<td><img src="a.png" width="40px" alt="a" title="a"></td>   
<td>Car</td>     
<td>1741</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>61</td>   
<td><img src="b.png" width="40px" alt="a" title="a"></td>   
<td>House</td>     
<td>4251</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please improve your question. I have removed/reformatted your question but it needs more detail and a specific question. I also removed the extra bit which someone else added, basically saying the same as this which should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible with pure css, you have to use some javascript

here is a script written in jQuery:

```
$('tr').hide().has('img[src=a.png]').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

With HTML only (as you say in the tags) your best bet is to delete the ones you don't want.

With JavaScript you can find the images with the `src` attribute equal to `a.png` then get the parent of the parent of that (the `tr`) and set its CSS `display` property to `none`.

Comment: Obviously easier with jQuery.